# ValueError: Invalid input shape for image. in keras model conversion to core ml

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, yolo, coremltools

I've trained my YOLOv3 network with darknet to recognize some obj in an image. All is OK.
I want to use weight file in iOS app, so following some tutorials I obtained keras h5 model from darknet weight file ancd I check that also h5 model works fine. OK.
Last step, using coremltools I tried to convert h5 model in coreml model usable under xcode.
Here I have the issue... last conversion is performed with this little py script:

```
import coremltools

....

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('yolorcgz.h5', input_names='image', class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image', input_name_shape_dict={'image': [1, 416, 416, 3]})

coreml_model.input_description['image'] = 'Takes a photo'
coreml_model.output_description['output'] = 'Prediction of obj in the photo'

coreml_model.author = 'SW Team'
coreml_model.license = 'Public Domain'
coreml_model.short_description = "YOLOv3 network trained for obj recognition"

coreml_model.save('yolorcgz.mlmodel')
```

when I run the script I've always have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coreml.py", line 9, in <module>
coreml_model =    coremltools.converters.keras.convert('yolorcgz.h5',input_name_shape_dict={'input1': [1, 416, 416, 3]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 760, in convert
custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 556, in convertToSpec
custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 305, in _convert
raise ValueError(errMsg)
ValueError: Invalid input shape for image.
Please provide a finite height (H), width (W) & channel value (C) using input_name_shape_dict arg with key = 'image' and value = [None,H,W,C]
Converted .mlmodel can be modified to have flexible input shape using     coremltools.models.neural_network.flexible_shape_utils
```

Any ideas on wht could goes wrong?
Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. I fixed it by changing `input_name_shape_dict={'image': [1, 416, 416, 3]}` to `input_name_shape_dict={'image': [None, 416, 416, 3]}`.

I am using Keras 2.3.1 and Tensorflow 1.14.0 and this worked for me.